# MoPub swift integration not working correcty

Tags: ios, swift, mopub

I'm trying to use MoPub with Cocoapods on a swift project. I set Cocoapods set to use_frameworks and my bridging header is set in the project's target pointing to MoPub's own briding header:

```
#import <mopub_ios_sdk/MoPub-Bridging-Header.h>
```

But XCode is still complaining when I try to use any objects frin the framework:

Use of undeclared type 'MPAdView'

Comment: is the bridging header set correctly in build settings?

Comment: did you uncommented "use_frameworks!" for use with swift within your podfile?

Comment: To make the process more streamlined, use Twitter Fabric, which includes MoPub, in your project. Fabric is a great tool! Here is the website: http://www.fabric.io

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I just used Fabric.